# Data persistence with the Google Places Web Service on Android

Tags: android, database, web-services, storage, google-places-api

I have run into a Problem.

Basically, google web services allows a maximum amount of 1000 requests per day unless you verify your credit card (which I as a student, don't have).

I am building an android application which will help you find food near you and give you tips and whatnot. But heres the problem. I have reached the daily cap multiple times just due to testing the app & debugging it... And that is a serious issue...

I know how SQLite databases & so on work, and how to use them, but is that the way one would go when using google places web services? Is that even allowed?

Here is the basic process of what is happening:

1. Open App & Get the users location
2. Search and Mark nearby food sources (restaurants & whatnot)

   - This is done via getting a HTTP request with "Place Search"
   - Place search itself deliveres little information, not enough, so I get a "Detail Search" for every place it finds.
3. All the results (Max. 60) are marked on the map and saved in a DataHolder class storing all the DataModel classes.
4. this works fine and as intended, also if I close and restart the app, it will "work". But it will redownload all the data and the details. As you can imagine, this busts my 1000 request limit pretty damm fast.

So is there a common practice/structure on how developers persist this "Google API" data? I feel the way im doing it very inefficient both for me and the user...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> If you are developing a web based application that only needs to search for places, and does not submit new places, you should use the Places Library of the Google Maps Javascript API rather than the Google Places API Web Service. The Places library assigns a quota to each end user rather than to each key. This means that your available quota increases with your user base rather than being capped at a fixed amount.

You can use Places API for Javascript https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places

It has all features of server version. You could try to use it with invisible WebView, or better with Rhino.